# $.get function not working on chromium-browser raspberry pi3 but working on chrome desktop

Tags: jquery, python, flask, chromium, raspberry-pi3

I have a function which is supposed to communicate with the flask server and get the latest state of the gpio buttons so that the color property of the buttons can be synced across all the clients. On desktop chrome the function works perfectly but on the raspberry pi chromium-browser the function isn't even being called by the client.

html code:

```
<div id="centerArea">
                    <div id="temperatureBox">
                        <div id="temperature">
                            <div id="temperatureValue"></div>&deg <sup>C</sup>
                        </div>
                        <div id="humidity">
                            Humidity: &nbsp;<div id="humidityValue"></div>%
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

<div id="buttonsBar">
                    <div id="buttons">
                        <button type="submit" value="Button1" class="sync" id="B1" name="B1" onclick="b1(); return false;">Button1</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="buttons">
                        <button type="submit" value="Button2" class="sync" id="B2" name="B2" onclick="b2(); return false;">Button2</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="buttons">
                        <button type="submit" value="Button3" class="sync" id="B3" name="B3" onclick="b3(); return false;">Button3</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="buttons">
                        <button type="submit" value="Button4" class="sync" id="B4" name="B4" onclick="b4(); return false;">Button4</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

flask code:

```
@app.route('/dhtTemp', methods=['GET','POST'])
def readTemperature():
    #sleep(3)
    dht22.trigger()
    temperature = str('%.2f' % (dht22.temperature()))
    return (temperature)

@app.route('/dhtHum', methods=['GET','POST'])
def readHumidity():
    #sleep(3)
    dht22.trigger()
    humidity = str('%.2f' % (dht22.humidity()))
    return (humidity)

@app.route('/B1status', methods=['GET','POST'])
def readBStatus():
    b1status = str(gpio.input(relayPins[0]))
    #b3status = str(gpio.input(relayPins[2]))
    #b4status = str(gpio.input(relayPins[3]))
    return (b1status)

@app.route('/B2status', methods=['GET','POST'])
def readB2Status():
    b2status = str(gpio.input(relayPins[1]))
    return (b2status)
```

javascript code:

```
function get_temps(){
$.getJSON("dhtTemp", 
    function(temperature){
        $('#temperatureValue').text(temperature)

    }
);
$.getJSON("dhtHum", 
    function(data){
        $('#humidityValue').text(" " + data)
    }
);
}

function get_Bstatus(){
            function get_B1status(){
                $.getJSON("B1status",
                    function(b1status){
                        if (b1status == "1"){
                            document.getElementById("B1").style.borderColor = "red";
                        }
                        else{
                            document.getElementById("B1").style.borderColor = "green";
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
            function get_B2status(){
                $.getJSON("B2status",
                    function(b2status){
                        if (b2status == "1"){
                            document.getElementById("B2").style.borderColor = "red";
                        }
                        else{
                            document.getElementById("B2").style.borderColor = "green";
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        }
        setInterval('get_Bstatus()', 1000)
```

weirdly enough the code for retrieving the temperature and humidity is functioning properly even though it is also using the same $.get function. But the server is not even getting any requests from the client to load the function get_Bstatus

the log for server-client interactions:

```
192.168.1.73 - - [18/Jul/2016 15:16:49] "GET /dhtTemp HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.73 - - [18/Jul/2016 15:16:49] "GET /dhtHum HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.228 - - [18/Jul/2016 15:16:49] "GET /B1status HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.228 - - [18/Jul/2016 15:16:49] "GET /B2status HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.228 - - [18/Jul/2016 15:16:50] "GET /B1status HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.228 - - [18/Jul/2016 15:16:50] "GET /B2status HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.228 - - [18/Jul/2016 15:16:51] "GET /dhtTemp HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.228 - - [18/Jul/2016 15:16:51] "GET /B1status HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.228 - - [18/Jul/2016 15:16:51] "GET /dhtHum HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.228 - - [18/Jul/2016 15:16:51] "GET /B2status HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.228 - - [18/Jul/2016 15:16:52] "GET /B1status HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.228 - - [18/Jul/2016 15:16:52] "GET /B2status HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.73 - - [18/Jul/2016 15:16:53] "GET /dhtTemp HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.73 - - [18/Jul/2016 15:16:53] "GET /dhtHum HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

the ip address ending in 73 is the client open on the raspberry pi 3 itself on chromium-browser and the one ending in 228 is the client open in chrome on a windows laptop. the functions B1status and B2status are never called by the client on the raspberry pi, even though the function call for the humidity and temperature goes through without any problems.

Which is precisely why i am simply not able to figure out why just those two functions are not working while the other two are working just fine.

There are no console errors in either of the clients and when the button is clicked on the client of the raspberry pi it is appropriately updated on the client on the windows system so the code is functioning as far as i can tell, just not on chromium-browser.

thanks

**UPDATE**

Apparently i just needed to set the interval on the functions separately. As seen in the previously linked javascript code the functions get_b1status and get_b2status were being called by the parent function get_Bstatus.

the code started functioning on all clients when i separated the functions and called them individually. So the update code looks like something like this:

```
counter1 = "";
counter2 = "";
counter3 = "";
counter4 = "";
function get_B1status(){
    $.getJSON("B1status",
        function(b1status){
            if (counter1 != b1status){
                if (b1status == "1"){
                    document.getElementById("B1").style.borderColor = "red";
                    counter1 = b1status;
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("B1").style.borderColor = "green";
                    counter1 = b1status;
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
function get_B2status(){
    $.getJSON("B2status",
        function(b2status){
            if (counter2 != b2status){
                if (b2status == "1"){
                    document.getElementById("B2").style.borderColor = "red";
                    counter2 = b2status;
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("B2").style.borderColor = "green";
                    counter2 = b2status;
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
function get_B3status(){
    $.getJSON("B3status",
        function(b3status){
            if (counter3 != b3status){
                if (b3status == "1"){
                    document.getElementById("B3").style.borderColor = "red";
                    counter3 = b3status;
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("B3").style.borderColor = "green";
                    counter3 = b3status;
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
function get_B4status(){
    $.getJSON("B4status",
        function(b4status){
            if (counter4 != b4status){
                if (b4status == "1"){
                    document.getElementById("B4").style.borderColor = "red";
                    counter4 = b4status;
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("B4").style.borderColor = "green";
                    counter4= b4status;
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
setInterval('get_B1status()', 1000)
setInterval('get_B2status()', 1000)
setInterval('get_B3status()', 1000)
setInterval('get_B4status()', 1000)
```

i even managed to put in a condition where the value of the button state is stored in a variable and if on the next interval the state has not changed then the function basically does nothing saving a little bit of processing requirement from the server.

Comment: Did you try invoking your function directly on the web browser console(F12): `get_Bstatus();`

Comment: Also what if instead of `setInterval('get_Bstatus()', 1000)` you write that line as: `setInterval(get_Bstatus(), 1000)`

Comment: @Hackerman i actually tried what you suggested but the result i was getting was undefined function or something so then i realized that maybe the function wasn't even being called so i went back and changed the way it was being called as shown in the edit. Thanks though. Also calling the function without being encased in limiters actually was creating problems for me, i had tried it earlier once before for the temperature and humidity functions as well and it just gave an error, don't remember what it was though, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

just try fetch() first install polyfills `npm i --save es6-promise isomorphic-fetch`

and then:

```
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
require('isomorphic-fetch');
```